# Chart Axes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, graph, charts, mschart

My requirement is to graph (scatter graph) data from 2 arrays. I can now connect the data from the array and use it on the chart. My question is, how do I set the graph's X- and Y- axes to show consistency in their intervals?

For example, I have points from X = {1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9} and Y = {7, 10, 11, 15, 18, 19}. What I would like to see is that these points are graphed in a scatter manner, but, the intervals for x-axis should be (intervals of) 2 up to 10 (such that it will show 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 on x-axis) and intervals of 5 for the y-axis (such that it will show 5, 10, 15, 20 on y-axis). What code/property should I use/manipulate?

**ADDED PART:**

I currently have this data:
x_column = {12, 24, 1, 7, 29, 28, 25, 24, 15, 19}
y_column = {3, 5, 8, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 19, 15}

each y_column element is a pair of each respective x_column element

Now, I want MyChart to display a scatter graph of the x_column and y_column data in such a way that the x-axis will show 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 and the y-axis will show 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20.

My current code is:

```
' add points
    MyChart.Series("Scatter Plot").Points.DataBindXY(x_Column, y_Column)
```

The code above only adds points.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas("Default").AxisX.Interval = 2
Chart1.ChartAreas("Default").AxisY.Interval = 5
```

Comment: thanks Mr. Michael. will try it later. too busy with some other things. i'll be informing you if that's the answer i seek. thanks again.

Comment: x-axis seems not to be sorted.. why is that?

Comment: what do you mean by not sorted?

Comment: @Michael Also set the `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties on both axes